# $ is not defined with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the jQuery.js, it says that `$ is not defined`. Following is my code, and I have tried the solutions, like adding the tag for jQuery first in HTML, change the logic of my code. However none of them work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow/wow.min.js"></script><script>new WOW().init();</script>
<srcipt src="js/manific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></srcipt>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js

```
$(function(){
  $("#work").magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image'
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: In isolation, your code seems fine. However are you calling `$.noConflict` somwhere? Also note that 1.6.2 is *very* old. You should update it ASAP

Comment: Are there any other errors on your console?

Comment: @WouterBouwman I would guess `$ is undefined`....

Comment: tilzOR this is not the solution. You have to search why jquery is not loaded in page. Are you sure the library is well present in page ? not in another masterpage, in a html comment, or a footer include ... Check your final source code with browser

Comment: Can you confirm your custom code appears *after* you `<script>` tags?

Comment: After the page has loaded, open the browser and enter `$` in the console. Does it give an error?  If not, then you're loading jquery fine but calling it before it's been loaded.

Comment: it works when I add the code in html with tag script

Answer (score 1):

Checklist for `$ is not defined`:

1. Open the console and check if Jquery file is loaded. The file may not be available due to slow connection, proxy setting, firewall setting etc.
2. Make sure that the Jquery file is not edited (not applicable when using CDN).
3. Make sure that you don't include Jquery twice. You may have use a custom version of bootstrap or other plugins that contains another version of Jquery inside their codes.
4. Make sure that your JS code is not above the Jquery implementation.If you have JS codes which runs as soon as loading (Not after DOM ready etc.), You have to move Jquery implementation in top of your document.
5. Make sure you have not typed `type="text/javascirpt"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`. (Not applicable in your case)
6. View page source and make sure that jquery implementation is not removed by server side codes like `response.clear`
7. Make sure your default scripting language is javascript. Otherwise you have to redefine script language by `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: for the first solution I try to download the jquery file through [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js), and include it on the top of all the js scripts, but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok I have added two items to checklist. Also try another version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

`$ is not defined` can be solved by downloading the full jquery file and not the minified version.

Use [this version](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js) and make sure that you have added it in your html.